# Prove boudedness of linear operator for Uniform Boundedness Principle

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Task:

[image]

I was studying these examples

- [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Banach-Steinhaus_Theorem), but it assumes here directly the linear boundedness
- [here](http://matrixeditions.com/FA.Chap3.243-244.pdf) pp. 243-244, but there is something strange starting from *Since each $T \in S$ ...* in my proposal. The link from showing $\| Au \| < \infty$ cannot be direct to show that $\|A_{k} - A\| \to 0$. There must be some stages missing.
- one proof of the theorem [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness_principle) but not about the boundedness of the linear operator so not sufficient

### My proposal

Let $X$ be a Banach space, $Y$ a normed space, $S \subset \mathscr{B}(X,Y)$, $D := X$ and let operators $A_{k} \in \mathscr{B}(X,Y)$ satisfy for all $u \in X$:
\begin{equation*}
\| A_{k} u \| < \infty, \, \text{ when } \, k \to \infty.
\end{equation*}
where $\| A_{k} u \|$ denotes the norm of the linear transformation $A_{k}$ from $X$ to $Y$. 
The sup of the $\|A_{k} u\|$ is not necessarily bounded.

Since each $T \in S$ is continuous, the inverse image of $T$ of a closed set is closed, and so 
\begin{equation*}
E := \cap_{T \in S} T^{-1} ( \frac 12 \overline{B_{Y}})
\end{equation*}
is closed in $X$. 
Let $x \in D$. 
Then there is some integer $n$ such that $Tx \in n B_{Y} \subset 2n( \frac 12 \overline{B_{Y}})$ for all $T \in S$. 
Because $E$ is fat and closed, $E$ must have an interior point in $X$. 
Let $x_{0}$ be any interior point of $E$. 
Then $-x_{0} + E$ is a neighborhood of $0$ in $X$. 
Hence, there is some $\delta > 0$ such that $\delta B_{X} \subset -x_{0} + E$. 
Let $T \in S$. 
Then $T(E) \subset \overline{B_{Y}}/2$, and since $x_{0} \in E$, we have $Tx_{0} \in \overline{B_{Y}}/2$, so that $T(\delta B_{X}) \subset -Tx_{0} + T(E) \subset \overline{B_{Y}}/2 - \overline{B_{Y}}/2 \subset \overline{B_{Y}}$. 
Hence $T(B_{X}) \subset \overline{B_{Y}}/\delta,$ so
\begin{equation*}
T(\overline{ B_{X} }) \subset T(2 B_{X}) \subset \frac 2\delta \overline{B_{Y}}. 
\end{equation*}
Since $T \in S$ was arbitary, $\sup_{T \in S} \|T\| \leq 2/\delta$, proving
\begin{equation*}
\| Au \| < \infty, 
\end{equation*}
where $A_{k} \to A$ converges strongly. 
Then
\begin{equation*}
\lim\limits_{k \to \infty} \| A_{k} u - Au \|_{Y} = 0. \, \square
\end{equation*}

### Addition to Svetoslav's answer about linearity

The **linearity** of $A$. Let $X$ be a normed space and $Y$ a Banach space. 
Let $M \subset X$ is a **dense subspace** of $X$. If $A : M \subset X \to Y$ is a bounded linear map, then there is a unique bounded linear map $\bar{A} : X \to Y$ (extension by continuity) such that $\bar{A}x = Ax$ for all $x \in M$. Moreover, $\|\bar{A}\| = \|A\|$.

For every $x \in X$, there is a sequence $(x_{n})$ in $M$ that converges to $x$. 
We define 
\begin{equation*}
\bar{A}x = \lim\limits_{k \to \infty} Ax_{k}. 
\end{equation*}
This limit exists becuase $(Ax_{k})$ is Cauchy, since $A$ is bounded and $(x_{k})$ Cauchy, and $Y$ is complete. 
We claim that the value of the limit does not depend on the sequence in $M$ that is used to approximate $x$. 
Suppose $(x_{k})$ and $(x_{k}')$ are any two sequences in $M$ that converge to $x$ and let $Ax_k'\to y'\in Y$, $Ax_k\to y\in Y$. Then
\begin{equation*}
\| x_{k} - x_{k}' \| \leq \| x_{k} - x \| + \| x - x_{k}' \|,
\end{equation*}
and, taking the limit of this expression as $k \to \infty$, we see that 
\begin{equation*}
\lim\limits_{k \to \infty} \| x_{k} - x_{k}' \| = 0. 
\end{equation*}
It follows that 
\begin{equation*}
\| Ax_{k} - Ax_{k}' \| \leq \|A\| \| x_{k} - x_{k}' \| \to 0, \, \text{ as } \, k \to \infty.  
\end{equation*}
Hence, $(Ax_{k})$ and $(Ax_{k}')$ converge to the same limit $y\equiv y'$, because $$0\leq \|y-y'\|\leq \|y-Ax_k\|+\|Ax_k-Ax_k'\|+\|Ax_k'-y'\|\to 0$$ when $k\to\infty$

The map $\bar{A}$ is an extension of $A$, meaning that $\bar{A}x = Ax$, for all $x \in M$, because if $x \in M$, we can use the constant sequence with $x_{k} = x$ for all $k$ to define $\bar{A}x$. The linearity of $\bar{A}$ follows from the linearity of $A$.

The fact that $\bar{A}$ is **bounded** follows from the inequality
\begin{equation*}
\| \bar{A} x \| = \lim\limits_{k \to \infty} \| A x_{k} \| \leq \lim\limits_{k \to \infty} \|A\| \|x_{k}\| = \|A\| \|x\|. 
\end{equation*}

It also follows that $\|\bar{A}\| \leq \|A\|$. Since $\bar{A}x = Ax$ for all $x \in M$, we have $\|\bar{A}\| = \|A\|$.

Finally, we show that $\bar{A}$ is the unique bounded linear map from $X$ to $Y$ that coincides with $A$ on $M$. Suppose that $\tilde{A}$ is another such map, and let $x$ be any point in $X$. We choose a sequence $(x_{k})$ in $M$ that converges to $x$. Then, using the continuity of $\tilde{A}$, the fact that $\tilde{A}$ is an extension of $A$, and the definition of $\bar{A}$, we see that
\begin{equation*}
\tilde{A}x = \lim\limits_{k\to\infty} \tilde{A}x_{k} = \lim\limits_{k\to\infty} Ax_{k} = \bar{A}x.
\end{equation*}

Sources

- chapter 5, Banach spaces, [here](https://www.google.lv/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAAahUKEwjGp5Cc04fIAhXC2SwKHTP1Ccs&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.ucdavis.edu%2F~hunter%2Fbook%2Fch5.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEmy5bgovpMQvw_EmLjv0W7B-gvBw&bvm=bv.103073922,d.bGg): Bounded Linear Transformation

---

I am not sure about how they define the strong convergence here: in Hilbert space? 
Which are necessities for it such that the bounded linear operator also hold. 
How can you prove more rigorously the boundedness of the linear operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **linearity** of $A$ is straightforward:
Let $\lambda\in\mathbb R$ and $x,y\in X$. Then we have
$$A(\lambda x):=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}{A_k(\lambda x)}=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}{\lambda A_kx}=\lambda \lim\limits_{k\to\infty}{A_kx}=:\lambda Ax$$
$$A(x+y):=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}{A_k(x+y)}=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}{A_kx}+\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}{A_ky}=:Ax+Ay$$

**Boundedness:** You have that for each fixed $u\in X:$ $\|A_ku-Au\|_Y\to 0$. This means that $\|A_ku\|_Y\to \|Au\|_Y$ (here $\|Au\|_Y$ is some finite number ). Therefore  $\exists M_u :\|A_ku\|_Y\leq M_u,\,\,\forall k\in\mathbb N$, i.e the quantity $\|A_ku\|_Y$ is uniformly bounded in $k$ for each fixed $u\in X$. Now, from the **uniform boundedness principle** (Banach–Steinhaus theorem) we get that $\|A_k\|$ (operator norm) is uniformly bounded in $k$, i.e $\exists M=const:\|A_k\|\leq M,\,\,\forall k\in\mathbb N$.

Using this and the triangle inequality, we get:
$$\|Au\|_Y-\|A_ku\|_Y\leq \|A_ku-Au\|_Y$$
Let $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary. Then
$$\|Au\|_Y\leq \|A_ku\|_Y + \|A_ku-Au\|_Y\leq \|A_k\|\|u\|_X+\|A_ku-Au\|_Y\leq M\|u\|_X+\epsilon$$ for big enough $k$. This means that $\|Au\|_Y\leq M\|u\|_X+\epsilon$ for each $\epsilon>0$, or equivalently $\|Au\|_Y\leq M\|u\|_X$ which shows the boundedness of $A$.

Comment: I added my proposal about linearity and boundedness in the body of the question. I think this bounded linear operator may be the same thing as the bounded linear transformation. Is it?

Comment: I corrected a little in your question (the part with the addition), but I have several Remarks:
1) The addition is a different thing than what is your original question. In the addition you prove another theorem, namely extension of a bounded linear operator by continuity. There you only need the space $X$ to be normed and the space $Y$ to be Banach.
2) On the other hand for your original question, you need  assumption that $X$ is a Banach space and $Y$ is enough to be only normed space.

Comment: Also see my addition in my answer for the linearity of $A$.